# What is this French saying?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

What is [this man saying in French](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mBgGKnQfzA)? I know he's saying a French idiom, but I can't tell what he's saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Les clochards de la Seine" or "Les clochards de la scène"

Comment: And what does that mean?

Comment: @Geremia It means tramps (homeless people) of the Seine (river) or of the scene (theater). Contrary to what the title of the video claims, this is not a proverb or idiom. It is a strange expression out of context.

Comment: @Gilles: Ah. The context, from where the video snippet was taken, was about what would happen to him if it weren't for his wife. ☺